# EE2 User Guide for v.2.1.0?

Tags: pagination

My company currently uses EE2 v.2.1.0, while the current version and User Guide is at 2.5.5. I'm looking for the 2.1.0 User Guide to better understand the older version of the {pagination_links} tag, which seems to fail as a paired tag, and older pagination API in general.

I've Googled and searched EllisLab's site for access to previous versions but have not uncovered any links. Does anyone know if and where this information might be available?

Comment: Not wanting to preach, but you should probably look at upgrading EE as soon as possible. EE versions especially before 2.2.0 were extremely buggy. A huge number of bugs have been fixed in the 2.5 years since 2.1.0 was released :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a download of the EE 2.1.0 Docs!

http://d.pr/f/LeSk/WpTT61nY

Brad